# Steam OpenID field key name

Tags: php, openid, steam, steam-web-api

I'm trying to find the key to get returned datas by Steam OpenID after the login.

With other OpenID provider we can call some keys, like this one `contact/email`, to get some datas.

For example with the `https://openid.stackexchange.com` if you ask for `contact/email` Stackexchange will return something like this

> "contact/email" => "foo@gmail.com"

Steam return only one data the `64-bit Steam ID` (http://steamcommunity.com/dev) but they don't say which key to use.

I already know the `"preg_match"` method to get this Steam ID with the returned link.

But I'm using a Symfony2 bundle who need this key.

Does somebody already find it, just know this key or know how to find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one time somebody need this info.

Steam only send 64-bit Steam ID on a steamcommunity.com link but don't provide any key to have this Steam ID.

It is not possible to get data from Steam OpenID with common key like

> "contact/email" => "foo@gmail.com"